# How to set screen to center when collapse closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script to set the screen center when a collapse are is active however it wont be return to the top if the collapse area is closed. Can you advise how to amend my script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Screen center when from load
$('.screen-center').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  var self = this;
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(self).offset().top - 103
    }, 800);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't really understand what you want `it wont be return to the top if the collapse area is closed`.. Probably you just need one more function for `shown.bs.collapse_off`. Or if you want to go back to the previous scrollTop, so save the current value before setting a new scrollTop and just use it later when collapse area is closed.

Comment: The collapse area is hidden and its only visible activated a CTA button. Also its in a lower area in the body therefore when its closed then it remains in the lower position and I would like it to animate scroll back to the top. Let me know if you need further details. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure I understand what you are trying to do, but what it looks like you're doing in your code is animating the whole html body's scrolltop to the *.screen-center position minus 103 pixels.  If you mean to scroll the window then use $window.scrolltop()

Comment: The collapse area is hidden and its only visible activated a CTA button. Also its in a lower area in the body therefore when its closed then it remains in the lower position and I would like it to animate scroll back to the top. Let me know if you need further details. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want the window to scroll back to the top of the page out do you want the collapsed area to scroll back to the top?   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(self).offset().top - 103
    }, 800);   tried to scroll the body element which isn't how you scroll the page.  $(window) gets the viewable window and you can use scrolltop() on that too scroll the page.  To scroll to the vet top should be $(window).scrollTop(0).  This will set the page scroll 0 pixels from the top.  However if you want to reposition an element in the page then $('element').offsetTop(some value) will position

Comment: That element some value from the top of it's parent element